# How to automagically have yaourt / makepkg add the armv6h platform to PKGBUILD?

Tags: archlinux, software-compilation

Thanks to [yaourt](https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Yaourt) it's pretty simple to install non-standard software. However in most cases I have to manually edit the `PKGBUILD` file from `arch=('x86_64' 'i686')` to `arch=('x86_64' 'i686' 'armv6h')` for the compilation to start. Is there any way to have this done automagically?

Answer (score 3):

You should not be changing the packages specified `arch array`. The architectures specified in the `PKGBUILD`s are the ones it has been tested against. [Here](http://archlinuxarm.org/packages) you can find a list of `PKGBUILD`s that are compatible for the `armv6h` architecture.

Also, using *aur helpers* such as `yaourt` is not the best way to do things. Yes, it makes things one command easier for you. But, it also can put you in a bind very easily. And you should really understand how tools like `makepkg` operate before attempting to work around them.

Trying to use `PKGBUILD`s from architectures other than your own by just simply adding your architecture to the `arch` array in the PKGBUILD is an extremely dangerous move. `Archlinux` and `Archlinux-ARM` are *not* identical (#archlinux and #archlinux-arm). Use packages that were built for your architecture and support your architecture.

**Edit:**
*If* you were using a **good** AUR helper like `cower` to download packages from the `AUR` and then building with `makepkg`. Then, you could use something like `makepkg -A` where `-A` would set `ignore architecture`

Comment: There are some cases that make sense to ignore the architecture, like many perl modules that are improperly marked as x86/x86_64 but they are actually architecture-independent.

Answer (score 2):

Yaourt will pass the `-A` flag to `makepkg` if `-A` is passed to `yaourt`:

```
$ yaourt -SA the-package
```