# How do I install a flash player on arch linux?

Tags: archlinux, video

I'm running a fairly fresh arch install.

I've tried `pacman -S gnash-gtk` but this doesn't work

How do I get midori or any other browser to play flash videos (youtube, Iplayer, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The package [`midori-flash`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Midori#Flash_plugin) is what you want. This isn't available in the normal package repository so you will first have to install [`Yaourt`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/yaourt).

You can then install the package from the AUR like this:

```
yaourt -S midori-flash
```

I've not checked to see if the package is available for arm, but if it is not then you will have to follow these [slightly more complicated instructions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5412/how-to-automagically-have-yaourt-makepkg-add-the-armv6h-platform-to-pkgbuild) on building from the AUR.

Comment: This does not work for me. A dependency for midori-flash is flashplugin - which doesn't compile on ARM.